# How to return values from JSON via dynamic array

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, hash

I have an array that holds values that I expect to use to retrieve results from a large JSON. I want to group the json like this

**my array example**, which is is dynamic.

```
    builder_options = ['status', 'statusCategory', 'key']
```

and I want to do this but withought specifying the index on the array because that obviously wont work when the array changes.

```
        jira_query.group_by{ |issue| issue.fields[builder_options.first][builder_options.second][builder_options.third] }
```

I just want a way to add my array to the json object that is 'fields' so i can look up the nested data without worrying about length or whether or not anything is present. **Thank you in advance**

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it have to be an Array? Could use make builder_options a hash with specific but optional keys?

Comment: i want a billion dollars without worrying about anything

Comment: does not have to be an array. it starts off like this actually "status.statusCategory.key" and I split it on the period.

Comment: you can try to write some recursive function and allocate all checks in it

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". You're missing the minimal JSON to demonstrate what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ruby 2.3+, see @dgmora's answer.

For older versions of ruby, you could use this poor man's dig :

```
    jira_query.group_by{ |issue|
      builder_options.inject(issue.fields){|h,key| h && h[key]}
    }
```

As an example :

```
issue_fields= {a:{b:{c: [:d,3]}}}
[:a, :b, :c, 1].inject(issue_fields){|h,key| h && h[key] } # => 3
[:z, :b, :c].inject(issue_fields){|h,key| h && h[key] } # => nil
```

It will dig through Arrays and Hashes, but an index for an Array should be an Integer.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. I had a feeling inject would work, but I was not fully understanding the way that it works for something like this. Your answer really helped, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but if you're using ruby 2.3.0+ you can try

```
issue.fields.dig(*builder_options)
```

[Dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) gets the data from the hash without raising errors because something is `nil`. The splat operator(`*`) will expand the array into arguments. So it's the same as if you would do `issue.fields.dig(builder_options[0], builder_options[1], builder_options[2]`

Comment: this is awesome, we are using ruby '2.2.1' on this project but when we upgrade ill go with this solution. thank you!